# JavaScript replace special HTML (&character; format) character in a String

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace the square root symbol which is written in html as "√" (`&radic;`).
I used the following line to replace it with a space but it does not change the String at all.

```js
dig = document.getElementById("dig").innerHTML;
dig = dig.replace(/'&radic;'/g, ' ');
console.log(dig);
```

```html
<div id="dig">&radic;25</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: dig = &radic;25

Comment: @Arwa are you accessing the `innerText` or `innerHTML` of an HTML element?

Comment: @Countour-Integral yes I'm accessing innerHTML

Comment: try to use `dig.replaceAll(radic, ' ');`

Comment: @Ivar tried before, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is valid if you are accessing the `innerText` or `innerHTML` atribute of an `Element`.

```js
let s = document.getElementById("sqrt")
console.log("Text", s.innerText)
console.log(s.innerText.replace(/√/g, ""))
console.log(s.innerHTML.replace(/√/g, ""))
```

```html
<div id="sqrt"> &radic;2 == 1.4142</div>
```

As you can see `&radic;` gets evaluated and it's value is then `√` instead of that. The javascript `replace` method cannot understand that `√` is `&radic` so you can just replace `√`.

Also there is no need to use regex, you can just do the same with `"√"`

Comment: A technical note: the HTML parser replaces `&radic;` and other character entities with their character representations before placing them in the DOM. JavaScript does not see the character sequence `&raddic;` when examining the DOM because it was never put there.